# angular-chart errors during factory initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I'm sure I've missed something because I can't get angular-chart to initialize properly.  The factory method is erring out during the initialization of the global tooltips.mode value on line 30 of angular-chart.js v.1.0.3.  Looking at the code, it seems that this error would be appropriate because the tooltips value is `undefined` at this point.

```
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.mode = 'label';
```

However, there seems to be a lot of success so I'm sure it's me.  Here is my basic setup.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
    <script src="/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/angular-chart.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="RootCtrl">
    <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
    <div>
        <canvas id="averageDistance" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data"
                    chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options"
                    chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride" chart-click="onClick">
        </canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

** main.js **

```
'use strict';

//create main module
angular.module('App', ['chart.js'])
    .controller('RootCtrl', ['$scope',
function ($scope) {

    $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
    $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
    $scope.data = [
        [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    ];
    $scope.onClick = function (points, evt) {
        console.log(points, evt);
    };
    $scope.datasetOverride = [{ yAxisID: 'y-axis-1' }, { yAxisID: 'y-axis-2' }];
    $scope.options = {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [
                {
                    id: 'y-axis-1',
                    type: 'linear',
                    display: true,
                    position: 'left'
                },
                {
                    id: 'y-axis-2',
                    type: 'linear',
                    display: true,
                    position: 'right'
                }
            ]
        }
    };
}]);
```

The above configuration/$scope properties were taken from http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

The page doesn't even load because the angular App gets an injector error when trying to create the chart.js module.  I am using AngularJS v1.5.8, Chart.js v2.1.6, and angular-chart.js v1.0.3.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have refered these 3 libraries

(i)angular.js

(ii)Chart.js

(iii)angular-chart.js

```
    https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js 
    https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.min.js
    https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chart.js/1.0.0-alpha8/angular-chart.js
```

Here is the working **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3qas1ar8/5/)**

Comment: Apparently my Chart.js file was corrupted.  Although the non-minimized header showed v2.1.6, using my local, non-minimized, version caused the problem.  Updating to the version from the CDN fixed it.